# How to inject dependencies in a SavedStateHandle-aware AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

Assume a view model like this:

```java
public class FooViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    @Inject public FooViewModel(Application app, SavedStateHandle handle, Bar bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to inject `Bar` using Dagger 2. I am developing on Android.

According to the [`SavedStateHandle` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle):

> You should use `SavedStateViewModelFactory` if you want to receive this object in `ViewModel`'s constructor.

However, the [`SavedStateViewModelFactory` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory) state that the factory is `final` which means I cannot inject `Bar` there, either.

So far, I have been injecting via a setter:

```java
    @Provides
    FooViewModel provideFooViewModel(ViewModelStoreOwner owner, Bar bar) {
        FooViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(owner).get(FooViewModel.class);

        viewModel.setBar(bar);

        return viewModel;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I want to use constructor injection, mark the `Bar` instance variable as `final` and eliminate the setter.

Comment: To answer this question, I need to know how you managed to get the ViewModelStoreOwner into the graph.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I used a `@Subcomponent.Builder` with a `@BindsInstance Builder withViewModelStoreOwner(ViewModelStoreOwner owner);` method. This I call in my fragment with `withViewModelStoreOwner(this)`. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide a `FooViewModel`, you need a custom implementation of `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`.

```
MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.withViewModelStoreOwner(this)
.withSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
.withDefaultArguments(this.arguments != null ? this.arguments : new Bundle())
.build();
```

and

```
    @Provides
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    public MyViewModel viewModel(ViewModelStoreOwner viewModelStoreOwner, SavedStateRegistryOwner savedStateRegistryOwner, Bundle defaultArgs, Application application, Bar bar) {
        return new ViewModelProvider(
            viewModelStoreOwner,
            new AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(savedStateRegistryOwner, defaultArgs) {
                @Override
                public <T extends ViewModel> T create(
                    String key,
                    Class<T> modelClass,
                    SavedStateHandle handle) {
                    return (T) new MyViewModel(application, handle, bar);
                } 
            }).get(MyViewModel.class);
        });
    }
```

Note:

1.) you only get `SavedStateHandle` inside the `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`, so you won't be able to get it into your graph.

2.) you can reduce the length of that provider by using https://github.com/square/AssistedInject. Theoretically AutoFactory would also work, but it seems unmaintained in comparison.

3.) you won't be able to get `@Inject` on your ViewModel.

This answer was partly adapted from https://github.com/Zhuinden/DaggerViewModelExperiment/blob/c3cbf0a5bc85467cec08755fcc152db5e8c55f91/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/daggerviewmodelexperiment/features/second/SecondFragment.kt#L32-L47 .

Comment: The posted code worked fine! Note: I didn't try `AssistedInject`.